# Force CSS priorities to be the way I want them

Tags: css

I want this CSS to have it's priorities exactly as the order they are in:

```
/*Highlight every second row in a .styledtable without .no-odd-row-higlight*/
.styledtable:not(.no-odd-row-highlight) tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    background:#eeeeee;
}

/*Orange highlight, normally used by PHP*/
.highlight-orange, .highlight-tds-orange td{
    background:#ff4000;
}

/*Yellow highlight, normally used by JS*/
.highlight, .highlight-tds td{
    background:#f7fe2e;
}
```

I understand the reason they aren't doing so is specificity, but I can't work out how to make it work as I want it to. How can I make the first rule the least important, the second rule override the first, and the last rule override them all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `!important` to **both** the second and the last rules. That way the second and the last override the first, but the last overrides the second only because it comes after it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember this, when two rules have the same weight, the last rule specified wins! .
 If the previous example were being declared and one of it is being set to !important, the one with the !important will have the highest priority!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control to change the definitions of all three:

```
.highlight.highlight {
    /*things*/
}
```

is strictly more specific than any rule with only one class, including a plain `.highlight`.